# ORA-00942: table or view does not exist .or We are not able to drop

Tags: sql, oracle

I am getting below error while creating/drop table.Can you please help me on solving this error

```
create table transclaimcounts_ITG401223
drop table transclaimcounts_ITG401223
```

*

> ERROR at line 1:
>   ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

```
create table transclaimcounts_ITG401223
```

*

> ERROR at line 1:
>   ORA-00955: name is already used by an existing object

Answer (score 3):

The [database object naming rules](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Database-Object-Names-and-Qualifiers.html#GUID-75337742-67FD-4EC0-985F-741C93D918DA) explain the namespaces, including:

> Within a namespace, no two objects can have the same name.
>
> The following schema objects share one namespace:
>
> - Packages
> - Private synonyms
> - Sequences
> - Stand-alone procedures
> - Stand-alone stored functions
> - Tables
> - User-defined operators
> - User-defined types
> - Views

The ORA-00942 error is saying there is no table or view with that name, so the ORA-00955 error must be coming from a different object type from that list.

Query the data dictionary to see what exists:

```
select owner, object_type
from all_objects
where object_name = 'TRANSCLAIMCOUNTS_ITG401223';
```

(Note that the name is in uppercase in the data dictionary, as you are not using a quoted identifier; you won't find the object causing your issue if you look for `object_name = 'transclaimcounts_ITG401223'`. That is explained in the same documentation.)

Then you will either have to drop or rename that; or pick a different name for your new table. We can't advise you which action to take, it's your schema. But don't drop anything unless you're 100% sure it should not exist, obviously.